# Question regarding partial fraction decomposition for $\int \frac{1}{x^2-4} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

We want to integrate

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2-4} dx$$

I have tried the following:

$$\frac{1}{(x-2)(x+2)} = \frac{c_1}{x-2} + \frac{c_2}{x+2}$$

I wanted to find out the value of $c_1$ by multiplying with  $(x-2)$:

$$\frac{(x-2)}{(x+2)} = c_1 + \frac{c_2 \cdot (x-2)}{x+2}$$

If I understood it correctly, we want $(x-2) = 0$ to cancel $c_2$ out.

$x \to 2$ leads to

$$\frac{2-2}{2+2} = c_1+ \frac{c_2 \cdot(2-2)}{2+2} \\
0 = c_1$$

But an online integration calculator says $c_1 = \frac{1}{4}$ and $c_2 = - \frac{1}{4}$

Where did I go wrong?

$$$$

Comment: You need to clear all the fractions first. Multiply through by $(x-2)(x+2)$.

Comment: You multiplied by $x-2$ then set $x=2$ so you basically multiplied both parts by zero. You should compare two rational fractions and find $c_1, c_2$ that work for all values of $x$ **except** $x= \pm 2$

Comment: In your third equation, you should have $\frac{1}{x+2}=c_1 + \frac{c_2(x-2)}{x+2}$, which leads to $c_1=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @Vasili The method is valid if the algebra is done correctly. It's the [Heaviside cover-up method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I missed that. Sorry and thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If we have the value of $c_1$, in which function do we insert $\frac{1}{4}$ to get $c_2$?

Comment: @Do the symmetric thing: now multiply through by $x+2$ to get $\frac{1}{x-2}=\frac{c_1(x+2)}{x-2} + c_2$, and evaluating at $x=-2$ gives $-\frac{1}{4}=c_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went wrong when you wrote $\frac{(x-2)}{(x+2)}$ , the $(x-2)$ already cancels with the previous $(x-2)$

It should be instead $\frac{1}{(x+2)} = c_1+ \ldots$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial fractions decomposition $\frac{1}{x^2-4} = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2})$. Then integrate as natural log functions.

$\int\frac{1}{x^2-4} = \frac{1}{4}\int(\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2})$ =
$\frac{1}{4}(\ln(x-2)-\ln(x+2)) = \frac{1}{4}\ln(\frac{x-2}{x+2})$

Answer (score 1):

For an easier way to do the decomposition, note that you can express the numerator as a difference whenever:

1. The denominator contains terms which are separated only by a constant, as in your question: In general, for $$  \int\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}dx,$$ you can write $$1=\frac{(x-a)-(x-b)}{b-a}$$ so that the integral is $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int\frac{(x-a)-(x-b)}{(x-a)(x-b)}dx$$$$=\frac{1}{b-a}\int \left(\frac{1}{x-b}-\frac{1}{x-a}\right)dx$$

In your case it is $$\int\frac{dx}{(x+2)(x-2)}$$$$=\frac14\int\frac{(x+2)-(x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}dx$$$$=\frac14\int\left(\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)dx$$$$=\frac14(\ln|x-2|-\ln|x+2|)+C.$$

2. The denominator contains terms of the form $(P(x))(k\cdot P(x)+M)$ where $k,M$ are constants and $P(x)$ is a polynomial (preferably linear or quadratic). You then write $$\int\frac{dx}{P(x)(k\cdot P(x)+M)}$$ as $$\frac 1M\int\frac{(k\cdot P(x)+M)-k\cdot P(x)}{P(x)(k\cdot P(x)+M)}dx$$$$=\frac1M\int\left(\frac{1}{P(x)}-\frac{k}{k\cdot P(x)+M}\right)dx$$ and proceed further.