# Partial fraction decomposition for $\int \frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2(3x+1)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

We want to evaluate the integral

$$\int \frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2(3x+1)} dx$$

What I have troubles with, is to understand the principle of partial fraction decomposition.

For instance, here we'd have

$$\frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2 (3x+1)} = \frac{c_1}{(1-x)} + \frac{c_2}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{c_3}{(3x+1)}$$

Sure, we could say

$$ c_3 = \bigg(\frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2 (3x+1)} - \frac{c_1}{(1-x)} - \frac{c_2}{(1-x)^2} \bigg) \cdot (3x+1)$$

but how does that help us?

How do we find out that

$c_3 = 2$, $c_2 = 1$ and $c_1 = 1$?

Comment: One of the denominator should be $(1-x)^2$ instead of $1-x$.

Comment: @ArcticChar No. The answer of that thread is difficult to understand and too long for a topic which should be coverable in a few minutes

Comment: Ok, have you learnt how to do partial fraction?

Comment: Say, for a simpler expression like $\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)(x+2)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x+2}$, do you know how to find $A, B$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501221/question-regarding-partial-fraction-decomposition-for-int-frac1x2-4-dx

Comment: Multiply the RHS,

$$c_3 = \frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{c_1(3x+1)}{(1-x)} - \frac{c_2(3x+1)}{(1-x)^2}$$

Then substitute $x=-\frac13$ to find $c_3$. Similarly for $c_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and efficient way of doing this is as follows:

When you have $$\frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2(3x+1)}=\frac{c_1}{1-x}+\frac{c_2}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{c_3}{3x+1}$$
Start by combining the RHS into one fraction with the same denominator as the LHS, and then just write out the numerators, i.e.
$$-x^2+x+4\equiv c_1(1-x)(3x+1)+c_2(3x+1)+c_3(1-x)^2$$

Note that the $\equiv$ sign indicates that this is an identity and must be true for any value of $x$. Therefore choose values of $x$ which make brackets zero (to avoid a simultaneous equation).

When $x=1$, we have $4=0+c_2(4)+0\implies c_2=1$

When $x=-\frac13$, we have $\frac{32}{9}=0+0+c_3(\frac43)^2\implies c_3=2$

Now that we have run out of convenient values of $x$, we can just choose any other value, such as zero. Or, more conveniently, compare coefficients such as the $x^2$ term, which gives

$-1=-3c_1+c_3\implies c_1=1$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh that's a lot easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start with: $$\frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2 (3x+1)} = \frac{c_1}{(1-x)} + \frac{c_2}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{c_3}{(3x+1)}=$$$$\frac{c_1(1-x)(3x+1)+c_2(3x+1)+c_3(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^2 (3x+1)}=$$

$$\frac{c_1(-3x^2+2x+1)+c_2(3x+1)+c_3(1-2x+x^2)}{(1-x)^2 (3x+1)}=$$$$\frac{x^2(-3c_1+c_3)+x(2c_1+3c_2-2c_3)+c_1+c_2+c_3}{(1-x)^2 (3x+1)}$$
Next, use that two polynomials are equal when all coeddicients are equal so:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-3c_1+c_3=-1 \\ 
2c_1+3c_2-2c_3=1 \\ 
c_1+c_2+c_3=4
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Solve the system and find what you need

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean with this statement: "Polynomials are equal when all coefficients are equal"? How do you get to $-1$ looking at $-3c_1 + c_2$?

Comment: They have equal coefficients of corresponding powers of the independent variable. On the left side, coefficient for $x^2$ is $-1$, on the right side it's $-3c_1+c_3$ (had a typo)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "coefficient for $x^2$ is $-1$". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @stepbysteptomathpro If you do not understand the answer, why have you accepted it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Because he put so much effort into it (and I'm just a retard for not understanding)

Comment: @stepbysteptomathpro: On the lhs we have $-x^2=(-1)\cdot x^2$

Comment: @Vasili But on the lhs for $c_1+c_2+c_3$ we have nothing. How do we get to $4$ there then?

Comment: @stepbysteptomathpro Accepting an answer is a signal to the community that you are satisfied with the given answer and that your doubts have been completely addressed. It discourages other people from providing alternative answers or from expanding. Do **not** accept an answer until you are done. If you want to reward "effort", then up-vote.

Comment: @stepbysteptomathpro: No, we have $4 \cdot x^0$ on the left. It's all about powers of $x$

Comment: Not a very efficient method IMHO

Comment: @stepbysteptomathpro Please do not use the word retard.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the coefficients directly
\begin{align}
c_2 = &\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-x^2+x+4}{3x+1}=1\\
 c_3 = &\lim_{x\to -\frac13}\frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)^2}=2\\
c_1 = &\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-x^2+x+4}{(1-x)(3x+1)}-\frac{c_2}{1-x}
-\frac{c_3(1-x)}{3x+1}=\frac13+\frac{c_3}3
=1\\
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know which limits to take?

Answer (score 0):

We first decompose the integrand into 2 pieces by letting
$$\frac{-x^{2}+x+4}{(1-x)^{2} (3 x+1)} \equiv \quad \frac{f(x)}{(1-x)^{2}}+\frac{c_{3}}{3 x+1} \tag{*}  $$
Then equating the numerators on both sides yields
$$
-x^{2}+x+4 \equiv f(x)(3 x+1)+ c_{3}(1-x)^{2} \tag {**}
$$
Putting $x=-\frac{1}{3}$ gives $\frac{32}{9}=\frac{16}{9} C_{3} \Rightarrow C_{3}=2$.
Rearranging (**) yields
$$
f(x)=\frac{-x^{2}+x+4-2(1-x)^{2}}{3 x+1}=-x+2=1-x+1
$$
Putting back to $(*)$ yields the decomposition as
$$
\frac{-x^{2}+x+4}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)(3 x+1)} \equiv \quad \frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}+\frac{2}{3 x+1}
$$